# What movie or TV series had crosses that were burned into people's necks, hypnotizing them?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember seeing this on tv when I was a kid (in 1980's).
I'm not sure whether it was a movie or a TV series.
I remember two things about it:

1. A cross was burned to the necks of people, and they became hypnotized or something like that.
2. People drowned in the quicksand (or through the sand)

Comment: Burned like a brand? Was there a scene where this happened? Do you remember anything else about the people e.g. what they wore, was there any indication of time period it was set in?

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like the movie "[Invaders from Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invaders_from_Mars_(1953_film))" from 1953, not the remake from 1986

> Late one night, youngster David MacLean (Jimmy Hunt) is awakened by a loud thunderstorm. From his bedroom window, he sees a large flying saucer descend and disappear into the sandpit area behind his home. After rushing to tell his parents, his scientist father (Leif Erickson) goes to investigate David's claim. When his father returns much later in the morning, David notices an unusual red puncture along the hairline on the back of his father's neck; his father is now behaving in a cold and hostile manner. David soon begins to realize something is very wrong: he notices certain townsfolk are acting in exactly the same way. Through his telescope, David sees child neighbor Kathy Wilson suddenly disappear underground while walking in the sandpit. David flees to the police station for help and is eventually placed under the protection of health-department physician Dr. Pat Blake (Helena Carter), who slowly begins to believe his crazy story.

### Trailer

Comment: To think I dismissed that one because they were discs and not crosses... But upon further inspection, you're totally right, [that soldier drowned in sand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GPHR.png). Have an upvote :) (and by the way, the movie is [on Dailymotion](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3zh0au))